Any idea what the point of this schematic is in the DC section?

The schematic below is taken out of an actual PCB. The motor is connected to the top (+-) but from the schematic it appears it is connected to the AC portion of the rectifier. What is totally unclear:

How is the rectifier powered if both AC sides are connected to "Neutral"
The DC part of the rectifier has a power transistor, 33V Zenner diode and 100 om resistor but this is a closed circuit - the motor is not connected to it.

Can anyone explain how this works?
Here is the rest of the schematics:



Edit: Link to complete schematic:
https://img.yumpu.com/62424300/1/4000x2506/-saeco-vienna-sup018-m5av1-8.jpg?quality=100

There  is enough detail clarity for me to answer this question. It was closed before I could post.

The "dc" section works with the 07K33 varistor to provide a fast, precise voltage clamp at 33V up to about 10A. The varistor in parallel will handle higher currents.

Russell, What I don't' understand is 1) the rectifier AC is connected to Neutral on both sides 2) The rectifier DC has the power transistor with a Zenner (33V)  but the motor is not connected to DC.

"1) the rectifier AC is connected to Neutral on both sides " Incorrect. The ac pins are connected across the motor as is RV6."2) The rectifier DC has the power transistor with a Zener (33V) but the motor is not connected to DC. " The circuit is not intended do supply dc voltage to the motor. It is there to clamp voltage spikes generated by the motor.   This is as far as I can go until the question is reopened.

We still don't have the full schematic. I assume that the wires marked N connect to neutral. Where does the line/live/phase wire connect to the circuit?

Problem with schematic: The "+" & "-" markings are not congruent with the polarity of the bridge diodes, refer D10 on your schematic.

Problem with schematic:  There are two nodes marked as "N" on the schematic, one connects to the TRIAC T8, the other to RV5 & R2.  I suspect the one connected to the TRIAC is actually the active of the AC supply.

Regarding your comment: "The DC part of the rectifier has a power transistor, 33V Zenner diode and 100 om resistor but this is a closed circuit - the motor is not connected to it."  This is not correct.  The motor is connected to T1, D14 & R22 via the diode bridge, D10.

I guess I don't understand which side is the input and which is the output. Actually both are "N" but the right side is connected through RV5. The "L" comes through TRIAC T3.

Russell, I looked at a voltage clamp on the DC side to try and understand how the DC side schematics interact with the AC side but couldn't find anything anywhere. Let me know if you have a source I can look at to educate myself. Also I don't understand how the motor connected to the AC side can have "+" and "-" i.e. DC supply when it is connected to the AC side of the rectifier. The question was reopened.

I added the diagram that shows where "L" is connected to as well

Do you have a clean schematic without all the scribbles on it - it is hard to read.  Where did this schematic come from?  Can you post a link to it?

https://img.yumpu.com/62424300/1/4000x2506/-saeco-vienna-sup018-m5av1-8.jpg?quality=100

I copied the link to the complete schematic to the OP.

It's a voltage clamp.
When the AC voltage is low, T1, D14 and R22 are basically OFF, and no current flows through them.
Update: the "AC voltage" here is the voltage across the motor terminals, the RED and BLU wires in your schematic.
But if the AC voltage exceeds the break-over voltage of D14 (Vz), then it turns on (current passes through it from cathode to anode), which turns on T1.  T1 then stays on and keeps the voltage between its collector and emitter quite constant, to a value of 0.7V above Vz (Vz + Vbe of T1).
T1 can sink a large current, since its gain is > 100; so if there is nothing limiting the current on the AC side of the rectifier bridge then it will probably heat up and fail.  You need to show the rest of the schematic on the AC side.
D10, T1, D14, & R22 is basically a "back-up" for the over-voltage protection that is provided by RV6.

Edit #1
Question 1 to the OP:
Please confirm these are the components used in the actual unit:
D10, B250C3700.
Diode bridge, 250VAC, 3A.
https://diotec.com/request/datasheet/b40c3700.pdf
D14, ZPY33.
Zener, 1.3W, 33V.
au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/ZPY33-TR?qs=6Fe8ASSgjNsaZBTJTu5bbg%3D%3D
T1, BD245C.
BJT, NPN, 100V, 10A, 80W, SOT-93.
au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/BD245C?qs=4wQOTo1SlKlM6git1ytfXw%3D%3D

Edit #2:
I am responding to the comment by the OP in the comments below:
Yes, I have a scope but the microcontroller is not sending control signal P11 to the optocoupler to open the TRIAC T3 so the circuit in question activates. Yes, those are the components on the PCB I am troubleshooting. –
Johnnie Walker 10 hours ago
Now that I have the complete schematic I can see how this part of the system works, which may give you a clue how to fault-find the system.  The motor in question (connected to JP8) is energised by the following path:
L, T3, "122 Ohmios" (yellow wires via JP8), motor via JP8, T8.
This is shown in the image below, which is the image you provided with the irrelevant parts removed.  The key point here is this: for the motor to be energised, two TRIACs have to be turned on simultaneously:  T3, and T8.
T3 is controlled by wire "P11".
T8 is controlled by wire "P17".
Component failures that can cause the motor to not run:
Open circuit:  T3, or "122 Ohmios", or T8, or R29, or ISO1, or R1, or R29, or the pins of the controller that drive P11 or P17.
Short-circuit:  D10, or T1, or D14.


@All - Although well-intentioned, the comments have become an ongoing discussion which is not an intended use of comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to this chatroom & should be continued there. || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per answer, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. Keep it in chat now, please!
